# splitting strings with multiple delimiters in python with re.split (from python cookbook)

Tags: python, regex, csv, cookbook

In Chapter 2, Section 2.1 of Python Cookbook 3rd Edition, you have the following:

```
>>> line = 'asdf fjdk; afed, fjek,asdf,      foo'
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'[;,\s]\s*', line)
['asdf', 'fjdk', 'afed', 'fjek', 'asdf', 'foo']
```

Yes it is a nice example... but when I try it out with removing the `\s*` in the regex it still has the same effect... see below:

```
>>> re.split(r'[;,\s]*', line)
['asdf', 'fjdk', 'afed', 'fjek', 'asdf', 'foo']
```

So, what does the author have in mind to make the redundant `\s*` useful for any other purposes than doing it without.. which is more simple and shorter?

Please make ur input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the book, so I don't know the authors' intent.  But David Beazley is as sharp as they come so I can only guess that it was to distinguish between the output for these two lines.

```
>>> line = 'asdf fjdk; afed, fjek,asdf,      foo'
>>> line = 'asdf fjdk; ; afed, fjek,asdf,      foo'
```

Using the regex from the book, the second line would be

```
['asdf', 'fjdk', '', 'afed', 'fjek', 'asdf', 'foo']
```

And using your modified regex

```
['asdf', 'fjdk', 'afed', 'fjek', 'asdf', 'foo']
```

Your regex will collapse all of the symbols in the group `[;,\s]` that are not separated by a character not in the match group.

Comment: thank u for ur input.. excellent example for using the book's regex.

Answer (score 1):

Both the regular expressions are different.

- The first regex states that, the delimiter should either be a comma, semi-colon or a space optionally followed by spaces
- The second regex states that, the delimiter should either one or more  comma, semi-colon or a space.

So going by the definition, you can easily find the difference if you apply the regex on the following string

```
line = 'asdf fjdk;; afed, fjek,asdf,      foo'
```

So the results would now vary

```
>>> re.split(r'[;,\s]*', line)
['asdf', 'fjdk', 'afed', 'fjek', 'asdf', 'foo']
>>> re.split(r'[;,\s]\s*', line)
['asdf', 'fjdk', '', 'afed', 'fjek', 'asdf', 'foo']
```

Now, what is the regex you want depends on what is your input you would work on and what is the desired output for all the acceptable test cases.

Comment: thank u for ur input.. excellent example for using the book's regex.